# Bot Service Basic Bot not responding to prompts

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

I've a Basic Bot Template based Bot set up using Bot Service. I've built a use case with few question prompts and capturing answers. I see the timestamp below my prompt in the chat box indicating that my prompt is delivered. But don't get a response back from the service. The application is still in develop and still haven't published it.

On Channels -> Web Chat -> I see few errors being logged.
Error: "There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code NotFound".

Could anybody help resolving this error?

Comment: Have you used ngrok to expose the bot?

Answer (score 0):

A 404 (Not Found) would imply there's something wrong with your bot's registration in the bot framework portal.  Can you log into dev.botframework.com, open your bot, hit edit, and see what the endpoint URL looks like?